# Modifying tasks.json to compile multiple c++ files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have 2 cpp files in `/home/misha/proga/c++again` folder: one with main function, and another with a function definition declared in the first one. I want to compile both of them. Here `https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson` it explains how to do that, but I'm stuck.

First, I build `C/C++: g++ build active task`. Second, I replace `${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp` instead of `${file}`. Then, if I run built task, it says that `g++: error: /home/misha/proga/c++again*.cpp: No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 and VSC 1.46.1

File1:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int sum(int, int);

int main(){
    cout<< sum(2,3)<< "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

File2:

```
int sum(int a, int b){
return a+b;
}
```

Comment: You've said `I have 2 cpp files in /home/misha/proga/c++again folder` bug you try to compile `/home/misha/proga/c++again.cpp` who don't exist because `c++again` is a folder and `c++again.cpp` don't exists
`${workspaceFolder}\.cpp*` should be `${workspaceFolder}\*.cpp` instead

Comment: I think it's better to have a `src` folder who contains all your sources files. When you compile with g++ and you want to take all your cpp files using the '*' selector. `*.cpp` it's like `all names possibles who ends with .cpp`
But `.cpp*` says `all files who begins with .cpp`

Comment: @Sunchock I actually have a "${workspaceFolder}\*.cpp" in tasks.json, but error is the same

Comment: Are you sure to have a '/' character between your folder's name and sources files names at the compilation time ?
Someting like `${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp`

Comment: @Sunchock Oops, I had \\ instead of /, because I followed the website in the question. Thanks

Comment: @Sunchock after building the task I get `> Executing task: /usr/bin/g++ -g /home/misha/proga/c++again/*.cpp -o /home/misha/proga/c++again/.vscode/tasks <


Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.`. How I can actually execute the code?

Comment: when you have compiled, it will give you a binary. You can launch it by some ways like open a terminal and calling it by enter`./binary` or create another task with VSC who doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216630/discussion-between-sunchock-and-mihail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As say in comments you try to compile `/home/misha/proga/c++again*.cpp` who not exists because the compiler try to compile all files in `proga` folder who begins with `c++again` and ends with `.cpp`

Be sure to have the `/` character between your folder's name and your sources files names at the compilation time.